# How do you connect a .Net Core 2 Api on Mac Visual Studio to a SQL Server running on a remote Windows machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-mac

I have a .Net Core Api with a simple GetAllUsers route running on my Mac. I would like to connect the Api to the SQL Server I have running on a Windows VM via Dapper or Entity Framework. I have searched far and wide, so any suggestions as to where I might find some clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just pass the connection string to the Windows VM?

Answer (score 0):

The mystery has been solved. I had to upgrade my version of Visual Studio, upgrade to .NET Core 2 and all is good. .NET Core 1.0 appears to have a bug that cannot connect an SqlClient? This was probably a repeat question.